# Material Button Icon is showing without color

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

I am using the following material button:

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/bFavourite"         style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton.Icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/main_dark_blue"
            app:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
            app:cornerRadius="0dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/heart_filled"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconPadding="0dp" />
```

`heart_filled` is a png of a red heart. However the icon is showing without any color (i.e., a white heart).
Why is the actual color of the image not showing?
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57237630/7254873

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this set `iconTint` to `null`

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnGoogle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_google"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:iconTint="@null"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:text="@string/string_google"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorBlueShade1"
            app:cornerRadius="@dimen/_20sdp"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Achieved output
[image: Material button with colored icon]

Comment: yeah, i was looking for this. Programmatically it is `btnGoogle.materialButton.iconTint = null`

Comment: Thanks for sharing, It feels bad to me to set @null in xml, I had issues with that in the past but they do advise us to do it that way. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1289

Answer (score 9):

Just need to add tint mode in the material button icon

`app:iconTintMode="multiply"`

Answer (score 8):

You can try to set the `iconTint` attribute of the Button:

```
app:iconTint="#ffffff"
```

Comment: I dont want to set the colors from xml. I want my png image to simply show . I have other buttons with way more complicated coloring and they are showing all as white

Comment: Yes I know how it is when you expect something to behave like **it should**, just like a white icon to be white, but in AS I've seen a lot of weird behavior (like icons not even showing) and in these cases if there is a workaround I take it. So if this works I suggest you do it. If not then there is trouble.

Answer (score 8):

If your icon has multiple colors, you will have to apply TintMode as well.

```
  app:icon="@drawable/ic_delete"
  app:iconTint="#ffffff"
  app:iconTintMode="multiply"
```

Using this will give you perfect icon design.

Answer (score 2):

The **`app:icon`** is tinted with the `app:iconTint` color provided by the style by default (`Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton.Icon` in your case).

You can override this behavior using **`app:iconTint="@null"`** to your button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton.Icon"
   app:iconTint="@null" 
   .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app:iconTint="@android:color/white"` because they mention this in docs [MaterialButton Docs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)

Comment: I dont want to set the color code. I want the png image to show as is